# In Draft.js can you have a style toggled as a default?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, wysiwyg, text-editor, draftjs

For the most part, I have a WYSIWYG text editor up and running properly. However, in the same regard when you open a new Google doc, and you see that the "text-align-left" in the formatting toolbar is already toggled on, I am trying to accomplish the same with my editor.

I've tried to implement this via using a `useEffect` that toggles the left alignment on render, but it doesn't persist after I click the editor. I believe this has something to do with the `focusEditor` callback, but I am not sure how to properly manage it. (Code and notes below)

(*Also, I realize the desired behavior is technically default as is, however, I'd like for it to be toggled on until another alignment style is selected.*)

**Current behavior**: When the component renders, the align left button is active. When I click the text editor, the style toggles off.

**Expected behavior**: When I click on the editor to focus, the `"ALIGN_LEFT"` button/style should remain active until an alternate alignment style is selected.

```
const editor = useRef<Editor>(null);

const focusEditor = useCallback(() => {
        editor?.current?.focus();
    }, [editor]);

// This useEffect should set ALIGN_LEFT as a default style
useEffect(() => {
    setEditorState(RichUtils.toggleInlineStyle(editorState, 'ALIGN_LEFT'));
    // eslint-disable-next-line
}, []);

const toggleBlockType = (blockType: string, index: number) => {
        return (e: MouseEvent) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const newState = RichUtils.toggleBlockType(editorState, blockType);
            setEditorState(newState);
        };
    };

const toggleInlineStyle = (inlineStyle: string, index: number) => {
        return (e: MouseEvent) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            let newState = RichUtils.toggleInlineStyle(
                editorState,
                inlineStyle,
            );
            const activeStyles = editorState.getCurrentInlineStyle().toObject();

            if (inlineStyle === 'ALIGN_LEFT' && activeStyles['ALIGN_RIGHT']) {
                newState = RichUtils.toggleInlineStyle(newState, 'ALIGN_RIGHT');
            }
            if (inlineStyle === 'ALIGN_LEFT' && activeStyles['ALIGN_CENTER']) {
                newState = RichUtils.toggleInlineStyle(
                    newState,
                    'ALIGN_CENTER',
                );
            }
            if (inlineStyle === 'ALIGN_CENTER' && activeStyles['ALIGN_RIGHT']) {
                newState = RichUtils.toggleInlineStyle(newState, 'ALIGN_RIGHT');
            }
            if (inlineStyle === 'ALIGN_CENTER' && activeStyles['ALIGN_LEFT']) {
                newState = RichUtils.toggleInlineStyle(newState, 'ALIGN_LEFT');
            }
            if (inlineStyle === 'ALIGN_RIGHT' && activeStyles['ALIGN_CENTER']) {
                newState = RichUtils.toggleInlineStyle(
                    newState,
                    'ALIGN_CENTER',
                );
            }
            if (inlineStyle === 'ALIGN_RIGHT' && activeStyles['ALIGN_LEFT']) {
                newState = RichUtils.toggleInlineStyle(newState, 'ALIGN_LEFT');
            }

            setEditorState(newState);
        };
    };
...

const selection = editorState.getSelection();
const blockType = editorState
    .getCurrentContent()
    .getBlockForKey(selection.getStartKey())
    .getType();

const isStyleActivated = (style: string): boolean => {
        return !!editorState.getCurrentInlineStyle().toObject()[style];
    };

return (
    <div>
            <div>
                {styleFormattingOptions.map((option: any, index) => (
                    <ToggleButton
                        key={index}
                        onMouseDown={toggleInlineStyle(option.name, index)}
                        active={isStyleActivated(option.name)}
                    >
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={option.icon} />
                    </ToggleButton>
                ))}
                {blockFormattingOptions.map((option: any, index) => (
                    <ToggleButton
                        key={index}
                        active={blockType === option.name}
                        onMouseDown={toggleBlockType(option.name, index)}
                    >
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={option.icon} />
                    </ToggleButton>
                ))}
            </div>
            <InputContainer onClick={focusEditor}>
                <Editor
                    // @ts-ignore
                    customStyleMap={customStyleMap}
                    editorState={editorState}
                    onChange={setEditorState}
                    placeholder="Click here to add a description..."
                    blockRendererFn={renderBlock}
                    handleKeyCommand={handleKeyCommand}
                    keyBindingFn={inlineCodeKeyBind}
                    ref={editor}
                />
            </InputContainer>
        </div>
)
```